# Can take incremental LVM snapshots in linux?

Tags: lvm

I have just made a lvm snapshot of /opt partition then mounted that lvm to a /data.Is there is any way to take incremental lvm snapshots ?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible
try this, to create new LV snapshot:

```
lvcreate --size 100M --snapshot --name snap /dev/vg00/lvol1
```

read more at [Red Hat Portal](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/snapshot_command.html)

Comment: This is full block, not an incremental or differential

Comment: If the lvm is --thin, then the --snapshots really can serve as incremental backup with copy-on--write. See https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/blob/devel/mock/py/mockbuild/plugins/lvm_root.py for exceptional example how to work with snapshots in LVM